# List Least Sold Products

Tags: collection, product-list, reports, ee-1.11

My Boss has asked my to provide a list of all products that have not sold in the last 3 months listed in order of most stock

I have hunted for some code I can hack already but found very little, I am surprised no one has asked this question.

I have been trying to modify the reports/product_collection but the results are inaccurate, I was thinking it might be as simple as changing the DESC to ASC in the best sellers listing and then add a date range
->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'asc')

however I think the collection is limited to products that have at least sold one of, which is not what we want

This is what I have been using but I am starting to think I should be using the sales/order_item_collection instead?

```
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');

?>

<ul>
<?php
$from = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", (time()-2592000));
$to = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());

$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addOrderedQty($from, $to, true)
->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
//->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $sku)
->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'asc')
->getSelect()->limit(50)->query();


echo ' 50 Products not sold from '.$from.' until '.$to.'<br><br><br>'; 

foreach ( $_productCollection as $prod ) :
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$_product->load($prod['entity_id']);

$num = (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); 

($i%2) ? $even = "class='even-li'" : $even = "";
?>
<li <?php echo $even ?>>
<div><a href="<?php echo $_product->getUrlPath() ?>" title="View <?php echo $_product->name ?>"></a>
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getUrlPath() ?>" title="View <?php echo $_product->name ?>"><?php echo Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($_product->name, 150) ?></a> ( <?php echo 'Qty in Stock '.$num ?> )
<p><?php //echo Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate(strip_tags($_product->description), 130); ?></p></div>
</li>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
</ul>
```

cheers
FireHorse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addPriceData()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addUrlRewrite()
            ->setPageSize(6);
        $collection->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(
                array('aggregation' => $collection->getResource()->getTable('sales/bestsellers_aggregated_monthly')),
                "e.entity_id = aggregation.product_id AND aggregation.store_id={$storeId} AND aggregation.period BETWEEN '{$fromDate}' AND '{$toDate}'",
                array('SUM(aggregation.qty_ordered) AS sold_quantity')
            )
            ->group('e.entity_id')
            ->order(array('sold_quantity ASC', 'e.created_at'));
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);
        return $collection;
```